# How can I check if my Android device is infected with Pegasus Spyware?

Tags: malware, virus

I am referring to this Spyware which as been on the news lately:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(spyware)

How can I check an Android device for it? I would prefer step-by-step instructions, even if they are very technical, to other answers like "install an anti-virus" program, if possible.

I deliberately leave out details about my OS and phone model because I have several I need to check, and because I believe this question can and should be made at a more generic level.

Comment: Although the question is on-topic here, but given the nature of the topic you are likely to get better answers in the infosec community at [security.se].

Comment: AFAIK, security researchers  don't have access to latest strain of Pegasus that is infecting Android devices to study, so updated information to help identify infections on Android devices is missing. For iPhone, Amnesty International produced a technical report and came up with some pointers that can help identify if an iPhone is compromised with Pegasus or not. See [NSO Group Pegasus Indicator of Compromise](https://github.com/AmnestyTech/investigations/tree/master/2021-07-18_nso)

Comment: Amnesty International also released a tool named MVT to help automate the tests to search for pointers that they think indicates a compromised Android or an ios device. See MVT tool here: https://github.com/mvt-project/mvt