# Prevention of Android devices being hacked

Tags: security, 9.0-pie

I keep seeing media articles saying that smart phones etc are being hacked, particularly by NSO Pegasus. I would like to know how this is done. I'm particularly interested in how to protect against it. I have Android 9.0 devices.

PS Apologies if this is off topic. If so, please post a comment stating where this question should be posted?

Comment: 1.) Discussion questions fit poorly for StackOverflow sites as specific questions are preferred. As your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71613043/295004) has a comment to a long blog post, all of the ways Android has been compromised  in the past would be too long. 2) Don't be a target for nation state class device hacking tools as well as using common sense when download apps 3) To check your own status, assuming you are using a desktop browser, click on your name or the icon associated with your name in the upper right of the top bar next to search.

Comment: Relevant: [How do I protect myself from Pegasus and alike malwares?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/220572/69534) -- my own question at [Security.se].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if my Android device is infected with Pegasus Spyware?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239491/how-can-i-check-if-my-android-device-is-infected-with-pegasus-spyware)

Comment: consider two facts 1) google and OEMs will always have own backdoors in propritary blobs for baseband/modem etc - you **are** already hacked at moment of using smartphone 2) You are not a person of interest, and *"nothing is eaten as hot as it is cooked"* (why should someone hack you if you already share your privacy on instagram, facebook, etc for free?) [fun fact](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2021/04/in-epic-hack-signal-developer-turns-the-tables-on-forensics-firm-cellebrite)