# Do Google & OEMs always have backdoors in Android devices?

Tags: samsung, security, google, privacy, baseband

In a helpful comment on [this Android Stackexchange question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246023/prevention-of-android-devices-being-hacked), prominent contributor [alecxs](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/170470/alecxs) states:

> google and OEMs will always have own backdoors in propritary [sic] blobs for baseband/modem etc - you are already hacked at moment of using smartphone

I have much respect for alecxs, and they have provided helpful answers to my questions in the past.  So when alecxs writes something I don't already know, I pay close attention and try to learn form it.

Is it accurate that Google and OEMs always have backdoors in Android, and therefore one should consider any Android smartphone to be already hacked?

If so, why does the baseband/modem require such a backdoor?

Comment: For a lot of Open Source enthusiasts every closed source blob is a horror. As they can't look into it they anticipate the worst which means that the blob is insecure and contains backdoors. That is my understanding of such statements.

Comment: [Rob Braxmann](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKqVMfkpsufF-9MLBhO7iiuMl615oD1hK) has some nice videos about

Comment: [1](https://kojenov.com/2020-09-15-hisilicon-encoder-vulnerabilities), [2](https://www.gnu.org/proprietary/malware-google.en.html), [3](https://redmine.replicant.us/projects/replicant/wiki/SamsungGalaxyBackdoor), [4](https://mythoughtsontechnologyandjamaica.blogspot.com/2015/03/NSA-CIA-smartphone-hack-Baseband-Processor.html), [5](https://qz.com/1131515), [6](https://www.kryptowire.com/news/kryptowire-discovers-mobile-phone-firmware-that-transmitted-personally-identifiable-information-pii-without-user-consent-or-disclosure)

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer like "Yes. I have a proof". But after [this](https://mythoughtsontechnologyandjamaica.blogspot.com/2015/03/NSA-CIA-smartphone-hack-Baseband-Processor.html) we don't have a reason to believe the other way.

Comment: what we **can** proof is the possibility of baseband hacking. Ralf-Philipp Weinmann [reverse engineered](https://www.osnews.com/story/27416/the-second-operating-system-hiding-in-every-mobile-phone) Qualcomm *"One of the exploits he found required nothing more but a 73 byte message to get remote code execution. Over the air."* (there is a 10 years old yt video about)

Comment: google itself [confirmed](https://9to5google.com/2021/06/19/massachusetts-massnotify-app) they can silently install apps without notifying you (although its no baseband hacking - google play required)

Comment: carrier can lock phone if you don't pay the bill
https://www.xda-developers.com/google-device-lock-controller-banks-payments